# Section bss and loading them to the memory

Tags: x86, operating-system, elf

Here https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter16/pintos/pintos_6.html it is written:

> The first step in main() is to call bss_init(), which clears out the
>   kernel's "BSS", which is the traditional name for a segment that
>   should be initialized to all zeros. In most C implementations,
>   whenever you declare a variable outside a function without providing
>   an initializer, that variable goes into the BSS. **Because it's all
>   zeros, the BSS isn't stored in the image that the loader brought into
>   memory. We just use memset() to zero it out**.

I highlighted a part I don't understand. Why bss section "equal to 0" causes that behaviour? The question is meaningful if and only if it is general point not implementation-dependant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing N bytes of all zero, all that's stored for the BSS is a length.

The entire point of having the BSS separate from the data section is to enable this space-saving.  So **it doesn't *cause* the behaviour, it *enables* it.**

You can think of it as run-length encoding for everything that can be initialized with zeros.

---

> So, what do we zero out?

The memory that we allocated when loading an image that says it needs an N-byte BSS.

Note that in non-toy OSes, all the BSS pages usually start out copy-on-write mapped to a single physical page of zeroes (shared system-wide).  When a process dirties such a page, it triggers a "minor" page fault and the kernel gives it a private zeroed page as backing for the now-dirty virtual page.  (And on return from the minor fault, the store instruction that faulted the first time execute successfully, causing a TLB miss to read the newly-updated page table.)

Comment: I see that if we have a N bytes equal to zero there is sufficient to remember only N. But, "We just use memset() to zero it out.". So, what do we zero out? It is said that there is no bss section in the image. Perhaps, a loader "insert" a bss section during loading to the memory. (but, in such situation I've not noticed it when I was reading the loader.S file).

Comment: The way this works is that the linker script (`kernel.lds.S`) has `/* BSS (zero-initialized data) is after everything else.*/
  _start_bss = .;
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
  _end_bss = .;` `.bss` section is placed at the end of the kernel. Since all the variables and data are zero the linker will not physically place them in the file (why add a bunch of zero space to the file).It just assumes that once in memory they will be zeroed out. Observe the linker script created some symbols `_start_bss` and `_end_bss`. These symbols will contain the virtual memory addresses where BSS will start and end.

Comment: @Gilgamesz : as a continuation of my last comment the next question is where do they actually get set to zero. This is done in `main` inside `src/threads/init.c` . You'll see in that file a call right at the start to `bss_init ();` that does `extern char _start_bss, _end_bss;
  memset (&_start_bss, 0, &_end_bss - &_start_bss);` . Basically it uses the variables created by the linker with the start and end address of the BSS segment and sets them to all zero with `memset`

Comment: @Gilgamesz End result is the linker script says the special `.bss` section will be at the end of the file, I will declare their virtual memory addresses and it will be upto someone (in this case function `main` to zero them out). Failure to zero them out can cause undefined behavior since code may actually expect zero initialized data (that is why the compiler placed them in the `.bss` section to begin with!), not garbage that may have been in memory to begin with.

Comment: @Gilgamesz : imagine you write some _C_ code and your program contains a global variable array that is  500 megabytes. Because it is global that 500 megabyte array has to be set to zero (That is required by the standard). But wait a minute, if you store the 500 megabytes of zeroes in the file you end up with a 500mb+ program that ends in all zero. So why put all those  zeroes in the file when the linker can say "hey I have a 500mb BSS section that isn't in the file but appears at the end of the program (kernel) and this is how big that section is and needs to be zeroes out before usage.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thanks as well, now it is clear. I see you know PintOS. Thanks for such deep explanation ( not necessary but I appreciate it!)

Comment: @Gilgamesz : I have a passing familiarity with Pintos and a number of other academically inspired kernels. I have a very good understanding of Operating System design on x86 and use that general knowledge to find what I am looking for when a specific question arises. Basically, I didn't know the specifics to answer your question right away, I had to review the code a bit before commenting. Pintos has been the subject of other SO questions in recent years.